# How to sort by other field in $geonear aggregation pipeline in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

My collection has this format.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52e5f94d83b45407f959e7ff"),

    "latlng" : {
        "coordinates" : [
            85.29035240000007,
            27.6663671
        ],
        "type" : "Point"
    },
    "name" : "Sujit Maharjan",
    "updates" : [
        {
            "status" : "I want to #buy 5 kg of tomatoes.",
            "picture" : [ ],
            "parent_tweet_id" : "0",
            "deleted" : 1,
            "tweet_id" : "428578269169205248",
            "time_stamp" : 1391015996
        }
        {
            "status" : "I want to #start #milk business who can help me ?",
            "picture" : [ ],
            "parent_tweet_id" : "0",
            "deleted" : 0,
            "tweet_id" : "108fd43a-7efa-404d-800d-0c30a5da06e5",
            "time_stamp" : 1391955084
        },
        {
            "status" : "@SantoshGhimire @bhanduroshan Connect to us for  #Dairy business",
            "picture" : [ ],
            "parent_tweet_id" : "432503201968168960",
            "deleted" : 1,
            "tweet_id" : "432517594026082304",
            "time_stamp" : 1391955208
        },
        {
            "status" : "@bhanduroshan Did you get my message ?",
            "picture" : [ ],
            "parent_tweet_id" : "432502654154334208",
            "deleted" : 0,
            "tweet_id" : "432788670463377408",
            "time_stamp" : 1392019838
        },
        {
            "status" : "this is tweet with images @foodtradeHQ http://t.co/3eL1351HWf",
            "picture" : [
                "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/BgLZ4YaCUAAsFTJ.jpg"
            ],
            "parent_tweet_id" : "0",
            "deleted" : 1,
            "tweet_id" : "433148076820156417",
            "time_stamp" : 1392105574
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I need to query updates in which users are within certain radius sorted by updates.time_stamp.

For this I used aggregation pipeline but $geonear query would sort from distance and limit the result.

This is the my pipeline in python

```
    geo_search = {"near": [float(self.lng), float(self.lat)],
                               "distanceField": "distance",
                                "includeLocs": "latlng",
                                "uniqueDocs": True,
                                "spherical":True,
                                "limit":100,  # this will cut off the possible results, and complexity increasing in increasing this number
                            }



    pipeline = []

    final_query = {"$and":query_string}

    if len(query_string)>0:
        geo_search['query'] = final_query


    geo_search['maxDistance'] = 0.01261617096

    geo_near = {
                    "$geoNear": geo_search
                  }


    pipeline.append(geo_near)
```

Answer (score 2):

With the [**`$geoNear`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) aggregation pipeline stage, this basically does the standard type of "nearSphere" or "near" like query but places the result documents in your pipeline with an additional field that is required for the `distanceField`.

This **must** be the first pipeline stage, where it can use an index:

```
 collection.aggregate([
     { "$geoNear": {
         "near": [ float(self.lng), float(self.lat) ],
         "maxDistance": 0.01261617096,
         "distanceField": "distance",
         "includeLocs": "latlng",
         "uniqueDocs": True,
         "spherical":True,
         "query": {
             "updates.time_stamp": {
                 "$gte": timestamp_cutoff
             }
         },
         "limit":100
     }},
     { "$sort": { "other": 1, "distance": 1 } }
])
```

Through the rest of the pipeline there is now the additional field as was defined in "distanceField", so in order to get the nearest results you pass this to [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/). And you can pass whatever you want to sort as this is what the pipeline stage does.

You can essentially act on the results with anything you like including additional stages like [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) etc. Of course if other information is relevant to the initial result then you use the "query" option for [**`$geoNear`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/).

Really to do what you want you need to "limit" the possible documents matched by using something in "query" much as shown. So the "nearest" documents returned are only those that match the additional criteria.

Comment: but the problem is that limit query will already have truncated other possible result since [mongodb](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) says **$geoNear returns documents in order of nearest to farthest from a specified point and pass the documents through the aggregation pipeline.**

Comment: @SujitMaharjan all of the fields in your document are returned unless you put a `$project` after the `$geoNear` to change this. You just pass the fields to the `$sort` stage that you actually want. This is what the answer says.

Comment: the problem is the **limit** field in $geonear. I need to sort on **all the result** within a radius.

Comment: @SujitMaharjan GeoNear by definition looks for the "nearest" documents, so the distance is the key. If you are looking to exclude results outside of a certain timeframe then you can always pass that criteria to "query" and/or just increase the "limit" and then sort your results and use the `$limit` pipeline stage instead. This does not change the nature of what the function does, but by tweaking those parameters you can work towards your result.

Comment: yeah I was using very high number in the limit field of $geonear but it was too slow.

Comment: @SujitMaharjan Trying to limit the "timestamp" values is the best advise I can give. That additional criteria rules out "older" results from the possible matches considered. MongoDB 2.6 and greater can generally handle "intersection" with another "standard" index. Just not another special one such as geo or text. At the end of this you can of course `$sort` as shown.

Comment: @SujitMaharjan Put that context into the answer to make that clear. This helps reduce the possible results.